# Null Reference Exception when Sorting or Searching any columns but Username

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, jqgrid

below is my code for sorting and searching columns in a JQGrid. It works fine on the first column but I get an Null Reference Exception on Sorting or Searching any other columns and I cant seem to figure out why it is doing this.

```
private PropmetEntities db = new PropmetEntities();

private DbSet<User> Table
    {
        get
        {
            return db.Users;
        }
        set
        {
            Table = db.Users;
        }
    }

[PrivilegeFilter(priv = Privileges.UserView)]
    public ActionResult Grid(GridSettings set)
    {

        //var raw = db.Users.AsQueryable();

        var vm = Table.Select(x => new UserGridModel()
        //raw.OrderBy(x => x.Username).Select(x => new UserGridModel()
        {
            ID = x.ID,
            Username = x.Username,
            EMail = x.ContactInformation.EMail,
            Surname = x.ContactInformation.Surname,
            Role = x.Role1.Description
        }).ToList().AsQueryable();
        ApplyGridSummarySettingsToGrid(set, ref vm);

        GridModel grid = new GridModel(set, vm.Count());
        grid.rows = vm.Skip((set.PageIndex - 1) * set.PageSize).Take(set.PageSize).ToList();
        return Json(grid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

 public void ApplyGridSummarySettingsToGrid(GridSettings set, ref IQueryable<UserGridModel> rows)
    {
        if (set.IsSearch)
        {
            rows = set.Where.rules.Aggregate(rows, FilterGridSummary);
        }
        rows = rows.OrderBy(x => x.Username);
        SortGrid(set, ref rows);
    }

 public IQueryable<UserGridModel> FilterGridSummary(IQueryable<UserGridModel> rows, MvcJqGrid.Rule rule)
    {
        switch (rule.field)
        {
            case "Username": return rows.Where(x => x.Username.ToLower().Contains(rule.data.ToLower()));
            case "EMail": return rows.Where(x => x.ContactInformation.EMail.ToLower().Contains(rule.data.ToLower()));
            case "Surname": return rows.Where(x => x.ContactInformation.Surname.ToLower().Contains(rule.data.ToLower()));
            case "Role": return rows.Where(x => x.Role1.Description.ToLower().Contains(rule.data.ToLower()));
            default:
                return rows;
        }
    }

private void SortGrid(GridSettings set, ref  IQueryable<UserGridModel> rows)
    {
        if (set.SortOrder == "asc")
        {
            switch (set.SortColumn)
            {
                case "Username":
                    rows = rows.OrderBy(x => x.Username);
                    break;
                case "EMail":
                    rows = rows.OrderBy(x => x.ContactInformation.EMail);
                    break;
                case "Surname":
                    rows = rows.OrderBy(x => x.ContactInformation.Surname);
                    break;
                case "Role":
                    rows = rows.OrderBy(x => x.Role1.Description);
                    break;
                default:
                    rows = rows.OrderBy(x => x.Username).ThenBy(x => x.ID);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (set.SortColumn)
            {
                case "Username":
                    rows = rows.OrderByDescending(x => x.Username);
                    break;
                case "EMail":
                    rows = rows.OrderByDescending(x => x.ContactInformation.EMail);
                    break;
                case "Surname":
                    rows = rows.OrderByDescending(x => x.ContactInformation.Surname);
                    break;
                case "Role":
                    rows = rows.OrderByDescending(x => x.Role1.Description);
                    break;
                default:
                    rows = rows.OrderByDescending(x => x.Username).ThenBy(x => x.ID);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

 public class UserGridModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public ContactInformation ContactInformation { get; set; }
    public Role Role1 { get; set; }
}
```

If I try to sort or search the Username Column it works fine but on any other column I get a Null Reference Exception here:

```
            GridModel grid = new GridModel(set, vm.Count());
```

Comment: Can you explain what setter of `Table` property does? `Table = db.Users;` it should throw StackOverflow exception, because you are assigning current value back to same property

Comment: is this line returning null? "set.Where.rules.Aggregate(rows, FilterGridSummary)"

Comment: The Table Property fills a DataSet with the contents of the table    `db.users`. The only null I get is at: `GridModel grid = new GridModel(set, vm.Count());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving all data from your table to in-memory list of `UserGridModel` objects which have properties `Email`, `Surname` and `Role`:

```
new UserGridModel()        
{
    ID = x.ID,
    Username = x.Username,
    EMail = x.ContactInformation.EMail,
    Surname = x.ContactInformation.Surname,
    Role = x.Role1.Description
}
```

Later instead of using these properties you are trying to access `ContactInformation` and `Role1` properties which either not-loaded or not exist in your model:

```
case "EMail": return rows.Where(x => x.ContactInformation.EMail.ToLower().Contains(rule.data.ToLower()));
case "Surname": return rows.Where(x => x.ContactInformation.Surname.ToLower().Contains(rule.data.ToLower()));
case "Role": return rows.Where(x => x.Role1.Description.ToLower().Contains(rule.data.ToLower()));
```

To fix your code quickly just use properties which you have filled:

```
case "EMail": return rows.Where(x => x.EMail.ToLower().Contains(rule.data.ToLower()));
case "Surname": return rows.Where(x => x.Surname.ToLower().Contains(rule.data.ToLower()));
case "Role": return rows.Where(x => x.Role.ToLower().Contains(rule.data.ToLower()));
```

But keep in mind that you have big problem here - you are dumping whole table into memory and then filtering list and selecting page of data. That should be done on database side.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set a `breakpoint`, run/attach the `debugger` and when you `break` at your breakpoint, step through your code, while examining each variable. Look for a `null` variable, that is used as a reference. For example, if  `ContactInformation` in `x.ContactInformation` is null, you will get that error oin this line

```
EMail = x.ContactInformation.EMail,
```

If you need a jumpstart on debugging in Visual Studio, look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn)

Comment: Can you give please give me an example of how I should do this?